# Can a Windows 8 partition be mounted in Ubuntu if "fast startup"is switched on?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, shutdown, hibernate, windows-8

I'm aware that when a Windows session is hibernated, its disk partition cannot be mounted in Ubuntu. By default in Windows 8, a hybrid shutdown/hibernate feature is used (fast startup) which hibernates the kernel session but shuts down everything else.

Is there any way to mount a partition in this hybrid shutdown state? Even theoretically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 8 - when sent to its fast-startup shutdown - does not actually shut down. It hibernates, which means that the session is stored and will be resumed - which obviously means the status of the partition should not change in the meantime.

As such, it flags the partition with a so-called `hiberfile`, which is a physical file on the partition that you will be prompted to delete when you try to mount a hibernated partition.

You can, however, mount the partition in question as read-only through the `mount -r` option. That will enable reading the files, but not writing to the partition.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll try mounting it read-only. That'll do the trick for what I need. Cheers!

Comment: @AaronHastings Any time!

Answer (score 1):

You could mount the partition read only. This should let you access the drive to read things. Mounting the drive read write would really not work out very well for you.

Answer (score 0):

Not safely, no.  One OS can not make changes to the partition while the other has it open.