# efi disk read error and secure boot error before GRUB splashscreen

Tags: installation, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, secure-boot

I have finally got Ubuntu and Windows 8 booting correctly under EFI on Dell i660. However I am seeing error message right before the GRUB splash screen -
error: efi disk read error. (x3)
These are followed by -
Secure Boot forbids loading module from 
/boot/grub/gettext.mod
Then it loads the GRUB2 splash screen for (GRUB version 1.99-21ubunutu3.10).
Is there something I can do to fix these errors.
/boot looks ok and boot-repair did not help. If I disable the Secure Boot in BIOS I get rid of the loading module error, but am still getting the efi disk read errors. Are there are logs that I can look at ? Nothing surprising in /var/log/*.log.

Thanks!

Comment: "Finally got Ubuntu and Windows 8 booting correctly" - what do you mean by that?

Comment: I had lot of trouble with Windows 8 changing NVRAM settings and preventing GRUB from loading. Finally was able to fix it from within Windows using bcdedit.

Comment: gettext.mod error is gone after multiple boot-repair runs with grub re-install.
Also, the efi disk read error seems to only happen after booting into Windows and then rebooting. It must be because I am using Windows bootmgr to load grub.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the "disk read error," I recommend you disable the Windows Fast Startup feature, as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211026/can-a-windows-8-partition-be-mounted-in-ubuntu-if-fast-startupis-switched-on) or [here.](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html) That feature is better called "Fast Corruption" in a dual-boot environment, since it can result in disk corruption. That *may* be what's causing the problem, but I can't guarantee that. It's also conceivable that you've got a defective disk, so running a [SMART test](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38566/how-can-i-check-the-health-of-my-hard-drive) on the disk may be worthwhile. If it shows bad sectors, replace the disk *immediately!*

As to the module error, I wouldn't worry about it, so long as GRUB works correctly; or you can disable Secure Boot. (Disabling Secure Boot will increase your risk of becoming infected by pre-boot malware, though.)